# Java: stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, android, binary-semaphore

I want to do stuff only when my service gets completely stopped.

So I made a public static variable initialized it to false, in `onCreate()`, to true and in `onDestroy()`, to false.

In my activity:

```
if(TripService.trip_service_state)
{
   stopService(newIntent(ProfileActivity.this,TripService.class));
   while (TripService.trip_service_state);
   do_stuff();
}
```

In my service:

```
public static boolean trip_service_state=false;

onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    trip_service_state=true;
}

onDestroy()
{
   trip_service_state=false;
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now when my service is running, app gets NOT RESPONDING message.

Comment: Do you want the `do_stuff();` function to execute after the while loop or inside it?

Comment: After the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `Service` is executed on the same thread as an `Activity`, the code which would set the flag to false can't be executed: the Activity method does never stop. That's why you get an ANR.

You can send a `Broadcast` from the `Service` to the `Activity` via `LocalBroadcastManager` instead. (The Activity would have to dynamically register and unregister a corresponding `BroadcastReceiver`)

Comment: Can i achieve the same functionality by some easy way?

Comment: @Rajat Aggarwal - ummm, this *is* the easy way. The point is that you have to let go in one component (Activity) so that the other component (Service) gets a chance to do its work and notify interested parties once it ihas finished. Of course you can also do the infinite loop in some other Thread than the UI-Thread but somehow I don't really like the idea of checking every few millisecs if something is still there - waste of energy. Similar to why "push" is better than "pull". Or you can use LiveData. Better from an architecture point of view, but certainly not easier

Comment: One other thing: Service.onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called